# Is there a python friendly function to calculate moving average for 3D data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, moving-average

I am trying to create a smooth contour map by using a simple moving average filter. I have a .CSV that has three column x, y (which are poisition) and z which is the heat at a given x,y. Each column has 23,236 value. I have tried 1d moving average seperatly for x and then for y. Given the size of the data it has been neither fast nor effective at smoothing. I would appricate any help. the code below plots the contour map.

[image: heat map on a 5x16 m grid]

```
df = 'D:/F1_amp .csv'
df = pd.read_csv("F1_amp.csv");
Z = df.pivot_table(index='x', columns='y', values='z').T.values
X_unique = np.sort(df.x.unique())
Y_unique = np.sort(df.y.unique())
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X_unique, Y_unique)

pd.DataFrame(Z).round(3)
pd.DataFrame(X).round(3)
pd.DataFrame(Y).round(3)

plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, 20, cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via `Convolution`. This approach is fast and easy to generalize.
For 2D convolution you could use `scipy.signal.covolve2d()`. You can vary the size and the values of the kernel, I used a constant `3x3` kernel as example.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sg

kernel_shape = (3, 3)
kernel = np.full(kernel_shape, 1/np.prod(kernel_shape))
z = sg.convolve2d(z, kernel, mode='valid')
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked with minor changes.
kernel = np.full(kernel, 1/(kernel[0]*kernel[1])) instead of np.size(kernel)